# Passing variable to class with threading

Tags: python, kivy, python-multithreading

I'm trying to pass a var from one class to another one, which is threaded (not sure if that's what's breaking it, or just my lack of understanding... probably the latter):

```
class Widgets(Widget):

    def Test():
        LogMe("test1")

    class LogMe(Thread, info):
        def __init__(self):
            Thread.__init__(self)
            self.start()

        def run(self):
            print(info)
```

So Test() should pass the value "test1", but despite adding and removing 'selfs' and moving it around (I really need to get my head around Python structure!) it's still not recognising 'info'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It would be more helpful if you describe what you are trying to do rather than your methodology for achieving that end.

Answer (score 1):

Your bug is here:

```
class Widgets(Widget):

  def Test():
      LogMe("test1")

  class LogMe(Thread, info): #you don't want to inherent info!!!!
      def __init__(self): #here you should get info as an argument 
          Thread.__init__(self)
          self.start()

      def run(self):
          print(info) #should be self.info - *if it was a member...*
```

Fixed code:

```
class Widgets(Widget):

    def Test():
        LogMe("test1")

    class LogMe(Thread):
        def __init__(self, info):
            Thread.__init__(self)
            self.info = info
            self.start()

        def run(self):
            print(self.info)
```

Enjoy ;)